# How do I calculate value of integral as an iterated integral?

Tags: integration

How do I solve $\int_{B}^{}f(x,y)d(x,y)$ as an iterated integral and sketch $B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

$f(x,y)=\frac{y}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}, B=\left [ 0,1 \right ]\times=\left [ 0,1 \right ]$.

First part:
How do I solve $\int_{B}^{}f(x,y)d(x,y)$ as an iterated integral?

I just put bounds and calculate it? Right?

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}dydx=0.222895$

How do I sketch this?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the y integral first we let $1+x^2+y^2 = u$ so $\frac{1}{2}du = ydy$ and we have $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{1+x^2}^{2+x^2} u^{-3/2}du =-u^{-\frac{1}{2}}|_{1+x^2}^{2+x^2}=-(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}).$$  So the resulting integral is:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx-\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}dx.$$  Can you take it from here?

EDIT:  I just realized you also asked for a sketch, unfortunately I cannot upload my own.  But if you are interested in a visualization wolframalpha is nice for this.  Just go to www.wolframalpha.com and type $\frac{y}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}, 0 <1, 0<y<1 $ you will get a nice representation.